# After creating tiles in QGIS by enabling VRT, I'm getting black color tiles

Tags: qgis, tiles

I have a big TIFF image and I created tiles of size 512 X 512 but all the tiles colour is black I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Can you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/332342/edit) your question and add more details about your input tif (`gdalinfo` or qgis layer properties) and exactly how you generated your tiles.

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS SE. Do you mean that you created a virtual raster using the Build Virtual Raster tool?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question clarify whether you have a big TIFF or a BigTIFF image (4+GB)